why does spring boot 3.2.4 give invalid signature error on token that is successfully validated by jwt.io?
I generate rsa keys like this:
# https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-token-access-control/docs/generate-rsa-keys

# create a privaate key
openssl genrsa -out jwtRSA256-private.pem 2048

#  extract a public key from the private key
openssl rsa -in jwtRSA256-private.pem -pubout -outform PEM -out src/main/resources/jwtRSA256-public.pem

I generate a token like this:
# derived from: https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-token-access-control/docs/generate-jwt-rsa-keys


# to run this script, make sure public and privte keys are created.
# see generateRSAkeys
# then run like this:
# ./generate-rsa-token > token

encode() {
  input=$1
  echo -n ${input}  | base64 | sed s/\+/-/ | sed -E s/=+$//
}

header=$(encode '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}')
payload=$(encode '{ "sub": "john", "scope": [ "role1", "role2", "GUEST" ] }')

signature=$(echo -n "${header}.${payload}." \
    | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign jwtRSA256-private.pem  \
    | openssl enc -base64 \
    | tr -d '\n=' \
    | tr -- '+/' '-_')
echo -n ${header}.${payload}.${signature}

The signature is validated by jwt.io:
https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicm9sZTEiLCJyb2xlMiIsIkdVRVNUIl19.ddnTlF-01NEAoYj6L_kbOUKCRyO2gSES2G4MmJNbDfv3CTdcg55rmf8D3zjrA6HiBT7WD7-05sv16SG83C4L-8ehx7L5_5LXqh5-eU9FTQLGMEu6P6JRoCXhAL4mfMhdVL18ar93vyT-eiDFPEvg7M9_L2RRpWUU-OB5ohq84poZB8uTqqoiCsymlxWgqGVcpyHRe-EJB9cgCq-Rck3i97QgfMV70MrV0N-VwMfjMSFjxMnjfHWPNZceRU2tWpmmMIeTGUXD0dY39mf-FFbgASaPRmgykUQPZIfPvK17SjH63oLt3ThSmePPuA-bZV_8tgC9opC6iWy1YvCD25OGzQ&publicKey=-----BEGIN%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0AMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAi5NgYU2sePws2eKZWxDd%0ATMvrA%2BerJsX7BoRYkTSxVKak%2FyM2LLUva5wQi0llHTvfYcnltXPr1XeqN8PphOFb%0A8BwGbtx4S8xtzDDVvMncYXI9gq9bxcKi7HgYEDwxFWfeYbLs2eeVmy81nDjUE%2BbI%0ALEdTvkmFfVb4MDynmfh6FbwSwQL57%2FQjvT539%2F0rqquJX%2FWePh3haBosC8XpBRBR%0AQuW9i0er1OIYVjrQSaXmiYm9mMg8qfGa7kJSrgR7bU7jxOx0lArf7dfLhludy5a0%0ADOUKI4uvaMsgj%2FaF0qAkJolTUJJ9pkJNnIWn63NifJJVqeWdG%2BEMF5h4tBceqSU7%0AKQIDAQAB%0A-----END%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----
This is the Spring Boot security configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AppJwtProperties appJwtProperties;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(appJwtProperties.getRsaPublicKey()).build();
    }

}

This is spring application yaml:
app:
    jwt:
        rsa-public-key: jwtRSA256-public.pem

This is the curl command and response:
+ curl -v -s --location http://localhost:8080/greeting --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyAic3ViIjogImpvaG4iLCAic2NvcGUiOiBbICJyb2xlMSIsICJyb2xlMiIsICJHVUVTVCIgXSB9.YXwk7TQ7jnvjGKXo0qElxcS3_WULGHZn03uwSyBYW1H3Lg6jJmRREXVKJfsqXk6g4-L6g_zxvMLW9GPJMTrlAa_otMdhhE37YrMQYZLEQj7Rv_ji8oTPwzfuam-iuzQVQlJhjyJmd02HsuCXa5In8JXV-iMFC1IO3Trfiz4UFtwaybeQPXGfsE8JFpEHwXCMQ31hNpX9NWVujKqWKE_jbqt399bc13s1dMGK8Zlpx8lvpTTkuyHffocTEdy64OvYjxU5IzYRyL4bqYLiepODls7gqz7AJibxqszCIokFUwaIvWnuNVhIGzsWYGWH4C94fbGh4IJw65u3IhQikColIw'
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080
> GET /greeting HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyAic3ViIjogImpvaG4iLCAic2NvcGUiOiBbICJyb2xlMSIsICJyb2xlMiIsICJHVUVTVCIgXSB9.YXwk7TQ7jnvjGKXo0qElxcS3_WULGHZn03uwSyBYW1H3Lg6jJmRREXVKJfsqXk6g4-L6g_zxvMLW9GPJMTrlAa_otMdhhE37YrMQYZLEQj7Rv_ji8oTPwzfuam-iuzQVQlJhjyJmd02HsuCXa5In8JXV-iMFC1IO3Trfiz4UFtwaybeQPXGfsE8JFpEHwXCMQ31hNpX9NWVujKqWKE_jbqt399bc13s1dMGK8Zlpx8lvpTTkuyHffocTEdy64OvYjxU5IzYRyL4bqYLiepODls7gqz7AJibxqszCIokFUwaIvWnuNVhIGzsWYGWH4C94fbGh4IJw65u3IhQikColIw
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2024 12:10:21 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

and the stack trace by spring service:
2024-04-19T08:10:21.138-04:00 TRACE 90136 --- [greetings] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder        : Failed to process JWT

com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJWSException: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:378) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:158) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]


Your script doesn't work. Try this one Creating a JSON Web Token (JWT).

@K.Nicholas, Thanks!   The scripts work for me.   They run successfully.  jwt.io validates the signature they produce.  Can you provide details on what 'doesn't work' means to you? Is your openssl a different version?  mine is: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023.

Sure. Your script doesn't create a valid signature part. I'm not sure what all those tr commands are up to but they are not the same as the link I pointed out.

jwt.io validates the signature generated by the script you provide, just like it validates the one I'm using (which I also found on the internet).  And spring boot does not validate the signature from the script you provided, just like it doesn't validate the signature of the script I found.

I had two errors in the script that generates the token.

a '.' appeared at the end of the input string to the signing step,
the encoding of the header and payload was incorrect.

Follows is corrected script.
#!/bin/bash

# derived from: https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-token-access-control/docs/generate-jwt-rsa-keys


# to run this script, make sure public and privte keys are created.
# see generateRSAkeys
# then run like this:
# ./generate-rsa-token > token

encode() {
 openssl enc -base64 \
  | tr -d '\n=' \
  | tr -- '+/' '-_'
}

header=$(echo '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | encode)
payload=$(echo '{ "sub": "john", "scope": [ "role1", "role2", "GUEST" ] }' | encode)

y="${header}.${payload}"
signature=$(echo -n $y \
    | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign jwtRSA256-private.pem  \
    | encode)
echo -n ${y}.${signature}

